How to implement real-time responses in a Flask-based chatbot with OpenAI Assistants API?
I have a basic chatbot that currently waits for the backend to fully process and generate a response before displaying it to the user. During this wait, the user sees a "Typing..." message. I want to enhance the user experience by displaying partial responses as they are being generated in real-time.
app.py (Flask backend):
import os
import logging
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from openai import OpenAI, AssistantEventHandler
from typing_extensions import override

# Initialize Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Set the OpenAI API key directly
api_key = os.environ.get('API_KEY')

# Initialize the OpenAI client
client = OpenAI(api_key=api_key)

# Define the assistant ID and vector store ID
assistant_id = "redacted_assistant_id"
vector_store_id = "redacted_vector_store_id"

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class EventHandler(AssistantEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.response_text = ""

    @override
    def on_text_created(self, text) -> None:
        self.response_text = ""
        print(f"\nassistant > ", end="", flush=True)

    @override
    def on_text_delta(self, delta, snapshot):
        value = delta.value.replace("\n", "<br>")
        self.response_text += value
        print(value, end="", flush=True)

    @override
    def on_tool_call_created(self, tool_call):
        print(f"\nassistant > {tool_call.type}\n", flush=True)

    @override
    def on_tool_call_delta(self, delta, snapshot):
        if delta.type == 'code_interpreter':
            if delta.code_interpreter.input:
                print(delta.code_interpreter.input, end="", flush=True)
            if delta.code_interpreter.outputs:
                print(f"\n\noutput >", flush=True)
                for output in delta.code_interpreter.outputs:
                    if output.type == "logs":
                        print(f"\n{output.logs}", flush=True)

    @override
    def on_message_done(self, message) -> None:
        self.response_text = self.response_text.strip()

def create_thread(initial_message):
    try:
        return client.beta.threads.create(
            messages=[{
                "role": "user",
                "content": initial_message
            }],
            tool_resources={
                "file_search": {
                    "vector_store_ids": [vector_store_id]
                }
            }
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error creating thread: %s", e)
        raise

def run_assistant(thread_id, instructions, event_handler):
    try:
        with client.beta.threads.runs.stream(
            thread_id=thread_id,
            assistant_id=assistant_id,
            instructions=instructions,
            event_handler=event_handler,
        ) as stream:
            stream.until_done()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error running assistant: %s", e)
        raise

def add_message(thread_id, user_input):
    try:
        return client.beta.threads.messages.create(
            thread_id=thread_id,
            role="user",
            content=user_input
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error adding message: %s", e)
        raise

@app.route('/start_conversation', methods=['POST'])
def start_conversation():
    try:
        initial_message = request.json.get('message', 'Hello')
        event_handler = EventHandler()
        thread = create_thread(initial_message)
        run_assistant(thread.id,
                      "Please provide the requested information and include relevant sections from the file search.",
                      event_handler)
        
        return jsonify({'thread_id': thread.id, 'messages': [event_handler.response_text]})
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error starting conversation: %s", e)
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

@app.route('/send_message', methods=['POST'])
def send_message():
    try:
        data = request.json
        thread_id = data['thread_id']
        user_input = data['message']
        
        event_handler = EventHandler()

        add_message(thread_id, user_input)
        run_assistant(thread_id,
                      "Please provide detailed insights based on the latest available data.",
                      event_handler)

        assistant_response = event_handler.response_text

        return jsonify({'assistant_response': assistant_response, 'status_updates': []})
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error sending message: %s", e)
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)


chatbot.js (JavaScript frontend):
let threadId = null;

document.getElementById('send-button').addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
document.getElementById('message-input').addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        sendMessage();
    }
});

function appendMessage(content, className, isUser) {
    const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
    messageElement.className = `message ${className}`;
    const avatarSrc = isUser ? "redacted_user_avatar_url" : "redacted_bot_avatar_url";
    const titleText = isUser ? "You" : "Assistant";
    messageElement.innerHTML = `
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
            <img src="${avatarSrc}" alt="${titleText}" class="rounded-circle" style="margin-right: 10px;">
            <strong>${titleText}</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="text"></div>
    `;
    document.getElementById('chat').appendChild(messageElement);
    typeMessage(content, messageElement.querySelector('.text'), () => scrollToBottom());
}

async function startConversation(initialMessage = "Hello!") {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://your-backend-url/start_conversation', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: initialMessage })
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.error) {
            console.error("Error starting conversation:", data.error);
            appendMessage(`Error: ${data.error}`, 'bot-message', false);
            return;
        }
        threadId = data.thread_id;
        if (data.messages) {
            data.messages.forEach(message => appendMessage(message, 'bot-message', false));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error starting conversation:", error);
        appendMessage(`Error: ${error.message}`, 'bot-message', false);
    }
}

async function sendMessage() {
    const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
    const userInput = messageInput.value;
    if (!userInput) return;

    appendMessage(userInput, 'user-message', true);
    messageInput.value = '';

    const respondingMessageId = 'responding-' + Date.now(); // Unique ID for the "Typing..." message
    appendMessage("Typing...", 'bot-message', false, respondingMessageId);

    if (!threadId) {
        await startConversation(userInput);
        return;
    }

    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://your-backend-url/send_message', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ thread_id: threadId, message: userInput })
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        
        const respondingElement = document.getElementById(respondingMessageId);
        if (respondingElement) respondingElement.remove(); // Remove the "Typing..." message

        if (data.error) {
            console.error("Error sending message:", data.error);
            appendMessage(`Error: ${data.error}`, 'bot-message', false);
        } else {
            if (data.assistant_response) {
                appendMessage(data.assistant_response, 'bot-message', false);
            }
            if (data.status_updates) {
                data.status_updates.forEach(status => {
                    appendMessage(status, 'bot-message', false);
                });
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending message:", error);
        appendMessage(`Error: ${error.message}`, 'bot-message', false);
    }
}

function typeMessage(message, element, callback) {
    let index = 0;
    function nextLetter() {
        if (index < message.length) {
            element.innerHTML = message.substring(0, index + 1);
            index++;
            setTimeout(nextLetter, 5);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    }
    nextLetter();
}

function scrollToBottom() {
    const chatBox = document.getElementById('chat');
    chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
}

window.onload = function () {
    startConversation();
}


Given my current setup and my goal of implementing real-time responses, which approach should I take? I've researched using WebSockets and Server-Sent Events (SSE) to potentially stream partial responses but haven't implemented them yet. Should I use WebSockets, SSE, or modify the backend to handle partial responses?
